# .htaccess rules to put a site offline while users are using it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, asynchronous, redirect, maintenance-mode

I am writing a .htaccess to be able to softly update my website, preventing new coming users to access it, and already connected users to be softly redirected, **taking account that there are some image rollovers, css styles and async PHP and js calls in the process that can be called within a displayed page without needing to reload a new page from the web site**.

Just redirecting anything to an update.php page would generate some unwanted effects on the pages that contains such things.

So I am fighting since days to find the correct set of rules to put in my .htaccess to achieve the following goal. Can you help me ?

If specialpage.php is called (even with parameters)
redirect to specialpage_redirected.php

If specialpage2.php is called (even with parameters)
redirect to specialpage2_redirected.php

if any other php file is called (even with parameters)
redirect to redirected.php

If specialscript.js is called
redirect to specialscript_redirected.js

If any other .js is called
redirect to redirected.js

and let all other files be accessed (css, images, ...)

... or if you have a better solution to achieve this goal to put the site offline for a maintenance, taking the previous constraints (already connected users on dynamic pages) into account.

Comment: `RewriteRule (specialpage)\.(php|js)$ $1_redirect.$2`

Answer (score 0):

Place these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(specialpage2?)\.php$ $1_redirected.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/specialpage [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ redirected.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(specialscript)\.js$ $1_redirected.js [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/specialscript [NC]
RewriteRule \.js$ redirected.js [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Do these statements take possible php page parameters into account, like page.php?i=1&b=test ? The $ just after "php" let me think that they don't.

Comment: Yes parameters will be rewritten as is. Query string is not matched in `RewriteRule` hence presence of `$` is only to match `/page.php`. Query string is automatically passed over to target URI.